# Installation of PyQt4

Tags: python, eclipse, pyqt4

I currently begin to use Python (2.7) with Eclipse(on windows). To run my script,I would need PyQt4 but I meet some problems when I try to install it.

I downloaded

- PyQt4-4.10.3-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.5-x64.exe,
- PyQt-win-gpl-4.10.3.zip
- and sip-4.15.2.zip

from the following link:  http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download .

I launched the execution of the first feature and a folder PyQt4 appeared into `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`.

To my mind, PyQt4 installation was finished and I simply did:

`Eclipse>Preferences>Pydev>Interpreter-Python>python27>Apply`

Nevertheless, when I try to import any function of PyQt4, I am said that the module name is unknown.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Restart eclipse. Actually first make sure that PyQT is installed, try it on the same version python interperer that is configured for eclipse

Comment: When I write "import PyQt4" in my python comand line, I have no Error message and help("PyQt4") also works. Does it validate the fact that PyQt is installed? (I am sorry I am really just beggining with programmation an related features).   But the problem is not solved in eclipse after eclipse restart.

Comment: Yes, PyQT4 is validated. Just make sure that it is same python interpreter, other than you can try reinstalling using this binary http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt . Or download the pyqt4 zip archive and install directly into the interpreter.

Comment: I appllied your first solution but when launching the executive file, I am said that the installer integrity check has failed.   I also tried to paste PyQt-win-gpl-4.10.3 into Python 27 (at different levels (directly in the python27 file or deeper in python27>lib>site-packages>PyQt4) ) but it is always unsuccessful

Comment: When I place the folder PyQt4 of python27>lib>site_packages in anaconda library, I obtain a new error message:"no module named sip" (instead of "no module named PyQt4") ...     Can it be considered as an improvement? xD

Comment: Thanks for the tip with restarting eclipse. I was puzzled why it wasn't working beforehand and a restart fixed it!!

Answer (score 0):

I want to comment for this .... but my reputation doesn't allow me to :(
anyway You could try this answer ..... (link below)

which is something like that :

**Copy from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8088374/6174268)**

> PyQt is actually a wrapping of C++ Qt libraries. So they are not .py
> files an
> d PyDev can't analyze them to
> get what is in them. You need to add PyQt4 in the Forced Builtins tab,
> so that PyDev can use a Python shell to "look into" those libraries
> and know what is in them. That will also give you code-completion for
> PyQt.
>
> Apart from that, it is usually not a good practice to use from foo
> import *. You'll be importing everything inside your namespace and you
> wouldn't know which is coming from where. Moreover you might have name
> clashes that mask each other. Though it is unlikely with PyQt, still
> I'd suggest you get used to from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore and
> reference classes like QtGui.QMainWindow.