# Eclipse does not autocomplete function arguments for PyQt4

Tags: python, eclipse, qt4, pyqt4, pydev

Eclipse will not autocomplete the function parameters in the PyDev perspective for `PyQt4.` All other aspects of the auto complete are working.

I am able to type `x  = QDia` and Eclipse lists of all classes/variables starting with `QDia.` However, I am in dire need for all having Eclipse show all of the constructors and function arguments.

I should mention that this feature does work for other Python modules. Something is different with PyQt4 and I can't figure it out.

```
System Details: RHEL5/RHEL6, Eclipse 4.3.1 (Kepler), PyDev 3.3 (I think), Qt 4.6
```

Comment: Not entirely duplicate but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082230/pyqt4-names-showing-as-undefined-in-eclipse-but-it-runs-fine/8088374#8088374) should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I already have `PyQt4` in the Forced Builtins Tab. That's how I am able to get auto complete to work as described above. Any other suggestions? Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the way that PyQt is wrapped doesn't expose that information (PyDev mostly imports the module in a shell, does a dir() and interprets the docstring to get information to show on to the user, but PyQt4 doesn't have that info -- and I'm not sure there's any automated way to get it).

So, usually when coding on qt I use the Qt Assistant a lot to get that kind of info... (or sometimes browse it on the web)

Comment: Actually it works on my Ubuntu build as expected. It's just on a RHEL5/RHEL6 setup where it doesn't work.