# Unresolved Import Error PyDev Eclipse QGIS plugin developement

Tags: python, eclipse, pyqt4, qgis

I am receiving Unresolved Import Error from PyDev in Eclipse and despite following SO posts, this one in particular:

[PyQt4 names showing as undefined in eclipse, but it runs fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082230/pyqt4-names-showing-as-undefined-in-eclipse-but-it-runs-fine)

I still can't solve this problem.

Like the above post I am trying to use the PyQt4 library.  I have installed it, and it exists here on my computer:

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt4

I have added it to the **PYTHONPATH** as the image below will show:

[image]

I have also tried adding it as an external library in the project properties as the below image will show (just in case):

[image]

According to the post referenced above because the library is C++ I need to add the PyQt4 library to the forced Builtins tab, this I have also done as shown here:

[image]

Yet I still get Unresolved errors as shown here:

[image]

And this is the stack trace:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not a "not found" error, rather is't an "invalid application" error. Googling your error pointed me to this post:

[ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)

Are you sure you have the correct (e.g. 32 vs. 64) architecture library installed?